# Batch file equivalent of Unix parameter expansion with quotes

Tags: windows, parameters, batch-file

There have been a lot of questions asked and answered about batch file parameters with regards to the `%*`, but I haven't found an answer for this.

Is there an equivalent syntax in batch files that can perform the same behavior as "$@" in Unix?

Some context:

```
@echo off
set MYPATH=%~dp0
set PYTHON=%MYPATH%..\python\python
set BASENAME=%~n0
set XTPY=%MYPATH%..\SGTools\bin\%BASENAME%.py
"%PYTHON%" "%XTPY%" %*
```

This is the .bat file that is being used a proxy to call a Python script. So I am passing all the parameters (except the script name) to the Python script. This works fine until there is a parameter in quotes and/or contains spaces.

In shell scripts you can use "$@" to take each parameter and enclose it in quotes. Is there something I can do to replicate this process?

Example calls:

```
xt -T sg -t "path with possible spaces" -sum "name with spaces" -p <tool_name> -o lin32 lin64 win32 <lots of other options with possibilities of spaces>
```

The command/file `xt` simply contains the code listed above, because the actual executable is Python code in a different folder. So the point is to create a self-contained package where you only add one directory (xbin directory) to your path.

Comment: Are you referring to the environment variables you are setting or the contents of `%*`? Can you give some examples?

Comment: @Keith_CE: You could use PowerShell and get rid of all this nonsense.

Comment: @Sinan I am refering to the contents of %*.  Does the example and explanation above help to make more sense?

Comment: @John That would be a nice solution except I can't have Powershell installed on all the machines that this might be run on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the cleanest solution is, but here is how I worked around the problem:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (%*) do set _args= !_args! "%%~i"
echo %_args%
```

**%_args%** will now contain a quoted list of each individual parameter. For example, if you called the batch file as follows:

```
MYBATFILE "test'1'file" "test'2'file" "test 3 file"`
```

**echo %_args%**

will produce the original quoted input.

I needed this for CMD files that take unfriendly file or directory names and pass them to Cygwin Bash shell scripts which do the heavy lifting, but I couldn't afford to have the embedded single quotes or spaces lost in the transition.

Note the **~i** in **%%~i%** which is necessary to remove quotes before we apply quotes. When a parameter containing spaces is passed (e.g., "test 3 file" above), the CMD shell will already have applied quotes to it. The tilde here makes sure that we don't double-quote parameters containing spaces.